# Jupyter Notebook Autocompletion (+tab) function does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

When I type the following code, nothing appears. I don't receive any error message or sth. Appreciate for any help in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.(+tab)
```

PS:Version of the notebook server is 6.4.0
Python 3.6.5

I am using my company's notebook I have not got Anaconda or any other programme installed. I am connecting python environment through a link and using that Jupiter notebook interface.

Comment: tag jupyter exists, too.
autocompletion takes a while to start, sometimes.